# PL/SQL Developer Test Window for Stored Procedure turns number value into scientific notation

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm using PL/SQL Developer using the Test Window to test a Stored Procedure that accepts a value of type Number. The value I'm passing to the Stored Procedure is 37788024213340161. However, I noticed that PL/SQL converts that value to scientific notation and rounds up, and passes a different value to the Stored Procedure instead: (3.77880242133402E16)

Thus, when executing the Stored Procedure, it ends up using the rounded-up value rather than the value I intended it to use. The value that ends up being passed to the Stored Procedure is 37788024213340200. Where the last 3 numbers should have been 161 but PL/SQL Developer rounded up and now the value is 200.

Is there a way to set the preferences in PL/SQL Developer so it will not change the value to use scientific notation in the Test Window?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh another thing you can try to do to view the full value in the Test Window of PL/SQL Developer is to switch the type from "float" to "string"

Comment: I tried your suggestion to change the type in the test window from float to string and it worked! Now the correct value gets passed into the stored procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are stored correctly in the database. The issue is only in the way that they are displayed to you.

I don't have access to PL/SQL developer right now. But, I think you can try this:
In the PL/SQL Developer's Preferences configuration dialog, check "Number fields to_char" on the SQL Window tab.

Comment: I already have the "Number fields to_char" setting checked. Even with this setting set, the Test Window still converts the value to scientific notation and passes in the scientific notation value to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: In Oracle, you can use the data type [number(precision, scale)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209) instead of number.  precision indicates the total number of digits and scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. Maybe setting the scale to the number of digits in Int64.MaxValue would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround

```
:numStr := to_char(:gecid);
```

This will add an output param "numStr". To see the numStr in the list of variables, press the arrow (black circle white arrow). For output param, you won't need to declare them.

Comment: Oh another thing you can try to do to view the full value in the Test Window of PL/SQL Developer is to switch the type from "float" to "string"

Comment: The issue is that the value I am passing into the stored procedure is being modified by PL/SQL developer. I'd like to see if there is a way to stop PL/SQL developer from rounding the value up, so that the stored procedure will use the correct value that I intended it to use.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to change the type in the test window from float to string and it worked! Now the correct value gets passed into the stored procedure. Thanks!