# CONCAT syntax getting wrong everytime

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day everyone, i have a simple problem yet it proves to be very time consuming. So im writing a select in which i want to take a string and concat it with a column

The result should look like this;

```
ERIP -> <suppliername>
```

I have

```
SELECT 'ERIP' || ' -> ' || s.suppliername,
s.supplierunn,
...
```

So far i've tried

```
SELECT CONCAT('ERIP', '->', s.suppliername),
       ...
```

Also

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('ERIP', '->'), s.suppliername),
       ...
```

Also

```
SELECT || 'ERIP' || '->' || s.suppliername,
      ...
```

I either get ORA - 01722 error or ORA - 00909

Can someone guide me please? with a small explanation will get a vote up also

As pointed out the WHERE statement was the problem.

Previously it was giving an error

```
WHERE ss.outserverid = '43'
```

Changed it to

```
WHERE ss.outserverid LIKE '%43%'
```

Comment: the first and the third one are correct.

Comment: Why you want to keep "->" separate from "ERIP" ?

Comment: ORA-01722 tells you an invalid conversion from string to number is taking place. As this code doesn't appear to involve any, I suspect the part of your query that you're not showing is actually to blame.

Comment: @RajniKewlani actually no particular reason just my quirk how i write :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert the part of the code im not showing are just joins and 1 where condition if you need it then i can show it but i doubt it will be any useful

Comment: I suspect you'll find the `JOIN`s or `WHERE` are involve an implicit conversion somewhere of rows that don't always convert. If you leave off this concatenation expression altogether, does the query still fail?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually i've double checked it right now, still fails with ORA-01722. I took out the where condition and it worked fine with CONCAT()

Comment: If you're trying to stuff a lot of code in a comment, don't. You can always [edit] your question to supply more detail. (Or delete it if you found and fixed the problem and it had nothing to do with your question.)

Comment: @Genx505 As you have already figured, the Where is the problem, I am guessing ss.outserverid is a NUMBER column. If you really do want to do the LIKE condition, try WHERE TO_CHAR(ss.outserverid) LIKE '%43%'

Comment: `concat()` is thoroughly documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONCAT.html). A test case demonstrating the issue always helps.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 SELECT 'ERIP ->'|| s.suppliername ..
    ..
    From <Table>
WHERE ss.outserverid = 43; -- Removes quotes across 43
```

Looks like column `ss.outserverid` is datatype `Number` and you are trying to equate it with a `varchar`. Try as shown above.

Edit:

Demo to clarify that `;` is not causing anything, Its a line terminator and should not cause any error:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> create table test(col number);
Table created

SQL> select * from test;
       COL
----------

SQL>
```

Comment: yes it works now when the WHERE condition got changed

Comment: @Genx505 Cool. you can close the question by accepting the answer then .

Comment: i really cant do that since you have ; which is not used in plsql 11g at least

Comment: @Genx505 What is not used in 11g atleast. Are you talking about `;` doenot work in `11g`. Sorry but i could not understand whats stopping you or you expect something else ?

Comment: yes exactly ; is not used in plsql developer 11g and will give out an error ORA-00911 invalid symbol

Comment: @Genx505 Seriously??? See my answer. Please note that `;` is a line terminator and it works on all the tool. If you get the error you mention that would had been coming from somewhere else ? Please check. Also i would suggest you to read some good books on SQL may be `ivan bayross` to get things clear. Read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-the-significance-of-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-sqlplus-commands

Comment: and yet in developer 11g it does not work in test window

Comment: @Genx505 I guess you also need to understand the use to `TEST` window in PLSQL developer. Its not to run queries rather to test a block or stored proc or any stored object. And compiler uses internally `;` wherever needed. Use a `SQL` window rather to run queries. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597312/pl-sql-developer-test-window-for-stored-procedure-turns-number-value-into-scient

Comment: Or you could use a Command window. It's worth noting that even if you're using PL/SQL in the test window, you can't have the `/` terminator either, but this is a PL/SQL Developer-ism, it's not standard for how most SQL and/or PL/SQL is run.